# Collection of functions

Tags: c#

in my csharp application i have certain events which should trigger functions to be called on a specific thread, which is looping through some code.

now, instead of storing all this data by hand and having a big switch-case i was wondering if it is possible to store these functions and their paramteres in a list which is then processed by the other thread?

pseudo code:

```
var func = pointer2somefunction(13, "abc");
list.add(func);
```

other thread:

```
while (list.Count > 0)
{
     var func = list.Remove(0);
     func.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: You can use [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx), which are C#’s version of function pointers.

Comment: Whichever method you use, ensure you use a thread-safe `List` to ensure that you don't get synchronisation issues between the threads.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using a `List<Action>` or a `Queue<Action>` which suits slightly better in my opinion. `Action` is a type for a no-parameter void *delegate*:

```
var functions = new Queue<Action>();

functions.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Foo"));
functions.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Bar"));

while (functions.Any())
{
    // note the double parenthesis here: one for Dequeue
    // and one for your dequeued function
    functions.Dequeue()();
}
```

If you need parameters, use `Action<T>` for one, `Action<T, T>` for two and so forth. For a return value, use `Func` instead of `Action` (or `Func<T>` etc.).

Maybe an *event* would help you too. Events are C#'s language feature to use the *observer pattern*.

```
// events are usually on the instance rather than static
private static event EventHandler MyEvent;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("FooEvent");
    MyEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("BarEvent");
    MyEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

An event is a *multicast delegate*, which is a delegate to a *list of functions*. You cannot control the threading for each handler though: Unlike the `Queue<Action>` above, where you can start or reuse threads, a multicast delegate is exposed as *one call* from outside, letting you use only one thread for all invocations.

Comment: @clamp Note that [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) is just a predefined type for a function with no parameters and no return value. If you want the functions to take parameters or return something, you can still do that, the type signature will just be a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are implementing events in that way. You don't need a big switch case, you need several events, and then trigger the right event in the right time, and register it with the right method.

You can do a list of delegates, but it'll start getting complicated when you want different function with different set of parameters.